# Как скрыть все запросы в метрику из вкладки Network

Tags: google-chrome

При отладке и просмотре вкладки Network в хроме очень мешают постоянные запросы в метрику. Есть какой-то удобный способ скрыть их, не отключая саму метрику? Отфильтровать по домену например? Мне не хотелось бы видеть никакие запросы в "https://mc.yandex.ru/webvisor"

Answer (score 3):

Ага, нашел. Вот так можно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто в фильтр `-mc.yandex.ru` добавил.